# Selectively reusing a DataType-keyed DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a project in which I want to display a collection of items of varying types - in my initial case `bool`, `string`, and `StringList` which is really just an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

What I want to do is render each item as an appropriate control that could edit that item - for example, CheckBox, TextBox, DataGrid.

I can accomplish all of that by adding DataTemplate resources keyed by DataType.  However, the issue here becomes being able to selectively reuse these templates without applying them project-wide.  After all, I certainly wouldn't want every piece of `string` content to become a TextBox!  Right now I've limited the scope by adding the resources to only a single control's resource collection,  which works great, except when I want to create a second control like this I'd be copying-and-pasting a lot of template code, which seems wrong.

What's the best way to permit selective reuse of this?  Here's an example of what I currently have:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value}" Padding="0,10,0,0" >
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
            <CheckBox Width="64" IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:StringList}">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="True" Width="100" Height="50">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Can you use a keyed DataTemplateSelector for this? (Not an expert on where you can use the Selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `DataTemplates` in a `ResourceDictionary` and add this `ResourceDictionary` to each `ContentControl` for which you want your templates to be applied:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Value}" Padding="0,10,0,0" >
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

**Dictionary1.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
        <CheckBox Width="64" IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:StringList}">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="True" Width="100" Height="50">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define your Data Template resources you want reuse selectively into a separated file ResourceDictionary then use them in your User controls by using merged dictionaries.

Have a look here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsldesigner/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight/

I hope it helps.